# What is the difference between AVAudioSession sample rate and AVAudioEngine input node sample rate?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I notice that  `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate` is 48000, while `AVAudioEngine().inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)` shows me a sample rate of 44100. When I do `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredSampleRate(16000)` it sets the input node sample rate, not the session sample rate. So my question is, what's the difference between the two sample rates?

I am trying to live record speech audio at 16kHz, but the audio comes out sounding distorted and metallic. I was wondering if it had something to do with the mismatch of these sample rates.